# Package and Deploy Yii2 Advance Application using phar

Tags: php, windows, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, phar

By referencing [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/packaging-your-apps-with-phar/) this link I've successfully packaged my simple PHP application. Now I want to package (create .phar file) of my entire Yii2 Advance application to deploy it on server.

I've followed all the steps given in the above link but when I run its giving me this error:

```
Warning: require(phar://D:/www/myphartest.phar/../../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: phar error: "vendor/autoload.php" is not a file in phar "D:/www/myphartest.phar" in phar://D:/www/myphartest.phar/index.php on line 5

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'phar://D:/www/myphartest.phar/../../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='phar://D:\www\myphartest.phar;.;C:\php\pear') in phar://D:/www/myphartest.phar/index.php on line 5
```

Following is my structure:

**D:\www\myphartest**

- build (directory)

  - config.ini
  - myphartest.phar
- src   (directory)

  - [under src => my yii2 advance applications files and folders]
- create-phar.php (file)

Here is my config.ini (inside build & www dir)

```
[database]
host=localhost
db=mydb
user=root
pass=root
```

There is index.php I've added inside src dir

```
<?php
require_once "phar://myphartest.phar/backend/web";
$config = parse_ini_file("config.ini");
AppManager::run($config);
```

run.php (inside www)

```
<?php
require "myphartest.phar";
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest use [box](https://github.com/box-project/box2) to create PHAR's. It just works :) and has additional features if you like.

It can be used in 3 simple steps:

- download the `box.phar`, see [box readme](https://github.com/box-project/box2)
- create config file `box.json`, see example below
- run `php box.phar build --verbose` (verbose to see the list of files that get into your phar)

Example config:

```
{
    "alias": "main.phar",
    "chmod": "0755",
    "directories": [
        "src"
    ],
    "files": [
        "README.md",
        "LICENSE"
    ],
    "finder": [
        {
            "name": "*.php",
            "exclude": [
                "tests",
                "Tests"
            ],
            "in": "vendor"
        }
    ],
    "git-version": "package_version",
    "main": "bin/main.php",
    "output": "main.phar",
    "stub": true
}
```

You can throw away most of the options. Just leave `main`, `output` and one of `files`, `directories` or `finder` for the box knew what to put inside of your phar.

I've tried it with Yii2 based console program - works fine!

Comment: Getting error: `C:\>curl -LSs https://box-project.github.io/box2/installer.php | php
curl: (7) Failed connect to box-project.github.io:443; No error`

Comment: File is downloadable. I think your problem is because of ssl certificate. Try cul -kLSs ... - 'k' to skip certificate checking.